# Using inside a repeater

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4, tempus-dominus-datetimepicker

Can this date picker be used inside a repeater via a class instead of the ID? I have a unknown amount of repeater data all of which contain the date picker

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: If you dont want to track what your users change its value to, sure. Otherwise you will need a more robust method to identify it so that if/when your users post that data back to you, you will know which dates are which.

Comment: No I need to track and save the  value of each date...I basically want multiple pickers on one page but the one piece of Js it initialize etc

Comment: In fact I have something to handle which dates are which in terms of the values...its just the date picker side of it...